# Drawing from GeoJSON data using GeoServer and Leaflet?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm using geoserver and leaflet. I'm working to drawing from geojson data. But not happen. From geoserver data's coordinates are [668560.565133,4543124.14345],[668519.713326,4543116.052449] etc. I tried coordsToLatLngs, but not happen. Projection is EPSG:4326. With trying getFeatureInfo.

How can I convert or draw?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting values like `668560.56 , 4543124.14` then you are not working with EPSG:4326. Those coordinates look like you are using some UTM coordinate system.

Double-check the coordinate system you are using for your data.

Comment: 4326 is working on WFS. Not working on WMS. I dont understand. Changed .prj file, added srs list. Maybe I thought a problem is geoserver version. I changed geoserver version. But not happened. How can I change utm to 4326 on geoserver?

Comment: If you are having those coordinates in a EPSG:4326, then you are doing it wrong. EPSG:4326 coordinates should be constrained to `[-180,180]` and `[-90, 90]`.